# laravel automatic injection when using from another function

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

I have automatic injection setup for a class (Mailchimp):

```
class Campaign {
    private $mailchimp;

    __construct(Mailchimp $mailchimp, someOtherArgument) {

    }
}
```

How can I instantiate the Campaign class without passing in Mailchimp?
My IDE (PHPStorm) asks me for the parameter, but I want Laravel to autoinject it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Laravel container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/container) to bind and resolve the `Campaign` class. In this case, Laravel will inject the `Mailchimp` class.

```
app(Campaign::class, ['someOtherArgument' => 'someValue'])
```

Comment: Unfortunately the IDE still complains about mismatching arguments. (The constructor requires 2 and I want to pass only 1 and have laravel add the mailchimp dependency).

Comment: @Chris please show the exact error you're getting now. Also, please show how exactly you're trying to resolve the `Campaign` class. I've just tested this approach in 5.5 and it works fine.